# Знак '+' в линке типа href="tel:"

Tags: html5, frontend

У меня есть линк: `<a href="tel:+contryCode_phoneNumber"`, при открытие его на телефоне открывается звонилка з номером но без знака '+', пробивал изменить плюс на два нуля, в итоге та же история.

Обязательно ли указывать знак + или 00 для звонков за границу? Если да то как можно это исправить?

Comment: Попробовал такую же операцию у себя на телефоне и код вывелся с плюсом, при условии что номер в tel начинался с +
Может помочь: https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-telephone-links/

Comment: Попробуйте `%2B` вместо плюса